# How do I open then close a connection based on Tasks in TPL Dataflow pipeline?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

### The setup

I have a pipeline processing many similar Tasks.  It has three segments in order, A, then B, then C (each of which may have multiple stages).  A and C are local to the machine, B is remote.

[image: Three stage pipeline, middle stage B is remote]

Tasks in section B, the remote section, need a connection to work.  They should all share one connection.

### The question

I want to create the connection when the first task moves from A to B, and close it when the last task moves from B to C.  How do I do this?

### The constraints

If it makes the solution easier I can accept one or more of the following constraints:

- Segment B has only one stage.
- Only one task in segment B at a time.
- Queues (buffers) or any other block inserted between A and B or between B and C.

Comment: Why share a connection? Connection pooling means that it costs next to nothing to open a connection and close it when you don't need it. This makes sense only if you want to share a transaction, which is not the best idea. What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

- Have a `connection` variable somewhere initially set to `null`.
- Whenever an item is processed, `connection` is created if needed and then used.
- After the block is completed (which you can find out using the `Completed` property, assuming you propagate completion properly), `Dispose()` the connection, if it has been created.

In code, as a helper method, it could look something like this:

```
public static TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateTransformBlockWithConnection<TInput, TOutput, TConnection>(
    Func<TInput, TConnection, TOutput> transform,
    Func<TConnection> connectionFactory)
    where TConnection : class, IDisposable
{
    TConnection connection = null;

    var block = new TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(
        input =>
        {
            if (connection == null)
                connection = connectionFactory();

            return transform(input, connection);
        });

    block.Completion.ContinueWith(
        _ =>
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Dispose();
        });

    return block;
}
```

(Note that this won't behave correctly if `connectionFactory` ever returns `null`. If you're worried about that, you can add a check for it.)

Usage example (this executes each string input as a SQL command and returns the result):

```
var block = CreateTransformBlockWithConnection(
    (string input, SqlConnection connection) =>
        new SqlCommand(input, connection).ExecuteScalar(),
    () => new SqlConnection());
```

Comment: That's a nice syntactically economical way to generate a new TransformBlock - thanks.